# Development environment for Zabbix

Tags: php, monitoring, zabbix, zabbix-api, zabbix-custom-reports

I am new to Zabbix and would like to improve a plugins funtionality. So far I am building a Virtual Machine to be able to run Zabbix locally. This seems to be the only way to actively work on the code in the same environment. Accessing the code from the host machine isnt so easy, so I have installed the GUI for Debain to work within the guest machine.

Is this the best way for developing or is there a better, more standard way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look into Docker containers, and all of the editors which can work with Docker.

For example, Visual Studio Code can attach its GUI to a backend-process running inside a container: see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers